# Handling Memory mapped File in C# directly from the memory

Tags: c#, .net, windows, c#-4.0, memory-mapped-files

Is it possible to open memory mapped file in C# directly just like opening files directly in windows,
say for example, I'm creating memory mapped file. through following code.

```
using System;
using System.IO.MemoryMappedFiles;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            MemoryMappedFile mmf = MemoryMappedFile.CreateNew("test.txt", 5);
            MemoryMappedViewAccessor accessor = mmf.CreateViewAccessor();
            var arun = new[] {(byte)'a', (byte)'r', (byte)'u', (byte)'n'};
            for (int i = 0; i < arun.Length; i++)
                accessor.Write(i, arun[i]);
            Console.WriteLine("Memory-mapped file created!");
            Console.ReadLine(); // pause till enter key is pressed
            accessor.Dispose();
            mmf.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

I need to open the file directly. Is it possible like opening file through

`Process.start("test.txt");`

from another process instead of reading values by the code .

```
 MemoryMappedFile mmf1 = MemoryMappedFile.OpenExisting("test.txt");
 MemoryMappedViewAccessor accessor1 = mmf1.CreateViewAccessor();
 var  value = accessor1.ReadByte(4);
```

If it possible to open memory mapped file directly? Please let me know.

Comment: Why are you using a memory mapped file just to do simple file operations on it?

Comment: though it simple file operation but difficult to access directly from memory isn't it?

Comment: Nowhere in your code you are accessing the content like your are reading memory.

Comment: @leppie: that's sample code ("say for example") intended to demonstrate what he wants to achieve, he presumably has a sensible reason to be using file mapping in his real code.

Comment: still i'm expecting to be actual file,yours not helpful

Answer (score 4):

> Starting with the .NET Framework version 4, you can use managed code
>   to access memory-mapped files in the same way that native Windows
>   functions access memory-mapped files, as described in Managing
>   Memory-Mapped Files in Win32 in the MSDN Library.

- [Memory-Mapped Files (.NET 4.0)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997372.aspx)
- [Working with memory mapped files in .NET 4](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/salvapatuel/archive/2009/06/08/working-with-memory-mapped-files-in-net-4.aspx)

Comment: all i get about read/write of memeory mapped file but i didn't get open memeory mapped file as a process

Answer (score 2):

The [MemoryMappedFile.CreateNew](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267552.aspx) method creates a file mapping object that is not associated with a file on disk.  So no, you can't open the file directly, because there isn't one.  (Such file mapping objects are backed by the system paging file, as [described here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366537%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).)

You can use the [MemoryMappedFile.CreateFromFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd987389.aspx) method instead if you want to associate the file mapping object with an actual file.